# Spring boot Gson custom serialization

Tags: spring-boot, gson

I am trying to move JSON serialization in my sprin boot app from default Jackson to Gson. I have added the managed dependency in the pom.xml and below properties in application.properties

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
spring.gson.enable-complex-map-key-serialization=true
```

The POJO that getting serialized is having a BigDecimal field which is causing below error. What is the correct way to provide the type adapter.

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: java.math.BigDecimal. Forgot to register a type adapter?
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:73) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter$1.write(TypeAdapter.java:191) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:658) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(GsonHttpMessageConverter.java:106) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted`

Comment: Could you please post your POJO.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue. It seems the class "Class" is not supported by default, so we need to register a type adapter as below.

**Solution**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Gson.class)
public class GsonConfig {
@Bean
public Gson gson() {
    return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Class.class, new 
TypeAdapter<Class>() {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Class value) throws IOException {
            out.value(value.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public Class read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            try {
                return Class.forName(in.nextString());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
    }.nullSafe()).create();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the handler method

```
@GetMapping(path = "/accounts", produces = "application/json")
public OutputParam getAccount(
        @RequestParam String refNum) {

    return service.getAccount(refNum);
}
```

And below the POJO that is causing the problem. It is in nested in the Output POJO. There is a BigDecimal class here which is causing the problem.

```
public class Column implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final String code;
private final Class<?> dataType;

public CIMColumn(String code, Class<?> dataType) {
    this.code = code;
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public Class<?> getType() {
    return dataType;
}

}
```